# Ubuntu Postfix server, what's the better spf check program, the one written in python or perl?

Tags: postfix

In Ubuntu there are two RFC 4408 compliant policy servers for postfix you can use. One is written in Python. The other is written in Perl. Any thoughts on which one is better? Thanks in advance

Comment: "two RFC 4408 compliant policy servers " means both work.  Pick the one you want. It is only there to service both perl and python users.